# What is password of ssh login for ssh over tor hidden services? Where can I find it?

Tags: ssh

I am following [this article](https://nurdletech.com/linux-notes/ssh/hidden-service.html) while trying to setup **SSH over Hidden TOR Service** and have completed all steps.

But when I try to do `ssh`, I receive error stating : `Permission denied`.

The article says :

```
HiddenServiceDir <directory>
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient stealth clientname1,clientname2,clientname3
```

> In this case, you can specify as many clients as you wish. Each client will get its own address and a password that allows access from that client. These addresses are not published in to directory. They can be found in <directory>/hostname.

- It specifis that each client gets its own password. **Where can I find this password ?**
- The `var/lib/tor/ssh` directory contains 3 files namely `client_keys`, `hostname`, `private_key`.

  **Where to look for password for `client1`, that I specified ?** Is it my machine's (raspberry pi) login password (as we normally use this login password for ssh over local network) or anything else ?

  Because I tried the login password of server but got `Permission Denied Error`.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: @JakeGould Also I uncommented the Clear Text Authentication in ~/etc/ssh/sshd_config still no progress. Do I need 2 restart any service after uncommenting clear text auth?

Answer (score 1):

Your SSH login information is the same as your SSH login information.

Tor does not change the way SSH or other application protocols work – it only changes the path.

---

However, hidden service passwords are **completely separate** from SSH login information.

At the bottom of the tutorial, with some clarifying notes added:

> If you took the extra step of hiding your hidden service using HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient, **you *[the client]* will need to add an entry to your torrc file** before you will allowed access:
>
> ```
> HidServAuth 7ei66g5djlymzxqb.onion op6npnLTq2NtpQVZqLJilB
> ```
>
> This line contains the address of your hidden service, and the authorization string **that was found in <directory>/hostname** *[on the server]*

(And if you didn't use HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient, there's no password.)

---

So in other words:

1. To *reach* the SSH server at all, you need the "authorization string" found in Tor's service directory – if you enabled this feature. If the authorization data is wrong, you *won't* get asked for a password at all: SSH will simply fail to connect.
2. To *log in* to the SSH server, you need the same SSH credentials as you normally use. The SSH server doesn't have the ability to distinguish between different Tor clients.

Comment: I have used HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient option & added the .onion address and Auto Cookie to Torrc file & in the Orbot's Client Cookie Setting (when I am trying to access from Mobile). Still when I type ssh raspi & hit enter to connect 1st asked for hash & typed yes. Then it asks 4 password & even aftr entering correct password, aftr 3 failed attempts 3 error msg "Permission Denied" (public key, password) appears on screen. Same password work with ssh over my WiFi but not over hidden service.

Comment: Also I uncommented the Clear Text Authentication in ~/etc/ssh/sshd_config still no progress. Do I need 2 restart any service after uncommenting clear text auth?

Comment: I have completed the setup as per specified in the article. How should I proceed further to perform ssh? Do I need to include extra parameter in front of ssh in terminal? Does password authentication works same as it works over local network? OR do I need to perform public key based authentication by generating key pair first? I haven't generated or used any pub-priv key pair yet.